My son passed away and I believe he had a bitcoin account. I would like to see about closing the account in favor of his minor child
My son passed away and I believe he had invested in bitcoin.  I would like to see about closing his account in favor of his minor child.  I have no idea how to do this.  We have a death certificate

I'm sorry for your loss, Bob.  Please take a look at the linked post, which has good actionable information.

It will only be possible if you have access to his wallet's private key (a long string of numbers and letters) or seed phrase (a suite of 12 or 24 words).
If you have one of those (make sure to not show them to anyone else!), you will be able to restore the wallet by entering the key/phrase in a Bitcoin wallet app, and finally access the funds.
